# order by numbers where can be hyphens - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query say

```
select * from table order by numbers asc
```

numbers are: `32,-,11,76,-`

What I get is `-,-,11,32,76` (hyphens at the start)

what do I change in query so I get the hyphens at the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here First I tried sort using conditional flow with type casting

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY numbers = '-', numbers+0 asc
```

If you want the reverse negate the conditional flow

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY numbers != '-', numbers+0 asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing numbers as varchar() and you will have more trouble while you have data like `1,11,9,5...` etc and ordering will have `1,11,5,9...`

Here is how you can manage it

```
select * from table_name 
order by case when numbers ='-' then 2 else 1 end,numbers+0 ;
```